# What is the order of properties precedence in spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, properties, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-consul

We have a springboot app which is using Consul for properties management. We have a boolean property in Consul which is set to false.

While starting the app, we have the same property set at command line argument as true.

What I observed is this property is taking the value from Consul and not from the command line argument.

What is the order or precedence here?

Comment: What version of spring boot and spring cloud are you using? Are you using bootstrap or `spring.config.import`?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent version: `2.5.4`
spring-cloud-consul-dependencies: `3.0.4`
We are using bootstrap.yml to connect to consul and read the values

Comment: Then consul has precedence